# I don't why parsing error in parsing list within list in python

Tags: python

Created a list that looks like this. Two lists within bigger list.

```
topics = [gender_subset = [3, 4],
age_subset = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

for t in topics:
        print(t)
```

But get this error:

```
Cell In[49], line 1
    topics = [gender_subset = [3, 4],
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That's not a valid list.

Comment: that's invalid. I don't see how we could explain this better than that: What you're trying to write has no resemblance with valid python; so, we don't even know what you thought this *should* be.

Comment: I've created a list of lists and want to parse through the top level to get to the elements in the lower list.

Comment: Assignments in python are *statements*, not *operators*. You can't assign variables like that (unless using the walrus operator `:=`)

Comment: What were you hoping the output would be?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the assignment operator in the way that you have. There are two alternatives:

1. Leave out the assignments and use indices to get your data

```
topics = [[3, 4],
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

for t in topics:
    for s in subset:
        print(s)
```

2. Use dictionaries to keep your labels

```
topics = {'gender_subset': [3, 4],
'age_subset': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}

for t in topics:
    print(topics[t])
```

Answer (score 3):

Python supports lists of lists, but you can't provide naming assignments to those inner lists. Given your goal I would use a dictionary instead, something like the following:

```
topics = {"gender_subset": [3, 4],
          "age_subset": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
for key in topics:
    print(topics[key])
```

with dicts you can also use more powerful queries such as getting all values

```
print(*topics.values())
```

or getting specific inner lists by name

```
print(topics["age_subset"])
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it,
Here's the solution

```
gender_subset = [3, 4]
age_subset = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
topics = [gender_subset, age_subset]

for t in topics:
    print(t)
```

Comment: Someone doesn't like our answers!

Comment: @nicomp either they are expecting more or he/she doesn't explain the question properly